# Adding a multiline comment within listing

Tags: listings

I'm creating a short document commenting on some C++ code. Part of what I'm trying to do is create blocks of text to the right of the code as in Numerical Recipes:
[image: Multiline block of text in code segment (Numerical Recipes)]

If it was just a bit of text, I would just have `escapechar=@` and add my single line of text in my environment. The nice thing about NR that I'm trying to emulate is a) multiline blocks of text (hopefully not broken up manually) and b) have multiple comments be aligned (when possible, depending on the code):
[image: Aligned comments in Numerical Recipes]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: this seems to have been abandoned, but surely you can provide more information, in particular a small compilable example showing what you've tried.  if you have found a solution, you could even post it as a self-answer.  otherwise it will be closed and disappear.